# can I check if a Java applet certificate is trusted before running my applet?

Tags: java, security, user-interface, applet, certificate

I have a signed applet on a website.  Because of this, the Java security dialog appears, and the user needs to grant permission to the applet before it can do it's work.  What I want to do is this:

- I want the website to explain the
  security dialog box to the user
  before it comes up.  The page will
  show some explanation text in a div,
  and after a few seconds, the security
  dialog will appear.
- If the user already allowed the certificate in a previous session, it should
  just run the applet without any extra
  dialog.

The problem is that the security dialog appears as soon as the applet is embedded in the page.  I can delay embedding, but there's no way to check it's permissions from the applet itself, since it needs to do it before it's loaded.

Perhaps I could load a second, normal applet that runs invisibly, and checks the permissions.  But how would I go about doing that?  Are there any Java classes that can check if a certificate has been trusted by the client?

Thanks.

Comment: As I know, the java security dialog appears only at the first applet launch. And if the user checks the box to Always trust the sertificate - the security dialog never appears again. But if the user chooses to trust it Once - it appears on the next launch. And you can't stop it programmatically for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the certificate and signature of a JAR file programmaticly, just as the JVM would when loading the applet.  It's not gonna be easy, but, at least at first glance, you're going to have to do this:

1. Use a hidden applet to download your JARs and verify their certificates, like the applet viewer would.  You can do this manually using the `java.security.cert` package.  The best way to figure out how to do that was the [`JarSigner` source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/security/sun/security/tools/JarSigner.java.htm), especially the `verifyJar()`.  Something like:

   ```
   // download the JAR
   URL url = new URL("jar:http://mywebsite.com/myjar.jar!/");
   JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   // get the certificates and other security stuff
   CodeSigners[] codeSigners = jarConnection.getJarEntry().getCodeSigners();
   Certificate[] certificates = jarConnection.getJarEntry().getCertificates();
   // verify the signatures
   // don't know the code, but you can analyze JarSigner example at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep2.html
   ```
2. Use [LiveConnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/LiveConnect) (maybe something else?) to set a cookie so you know "if the user already allowed the certificate in a previous session".
3. Launch your applet, possibly depending on the results of (1) stores in cookies created in (2).

I haven't give this that much thought, so there might be a better way.   Good luck, and post back!

Comment: I thought JarSigner was only used to sign an applet?  I couldn't find in the source how to access the end-users trusted certificates.

I'm not too familiar with how certificates and keystores work, or even what exactly a keystore is.  When I self signed my applet, I created a keystore on my development machine and ran JarSigner to sign it.  When I deploy the applet on my website, the user chooses to accept or reject the permission request.  Is that just an application setting, kind of like a 'remember my password' thing?  Or is it being stored in a 'keystore' somewhere.

Comment: @terence: The `JarSigner` code has methods for signing and verifying.  The function `verifyJar()` does that.  If you're not familiar with how keystores/certificates work, I highly recommend tutorials like [Signed Applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) and [Verifying a Signature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/versig.html).  Also, when you deploy an applet, the accept/reject is an application setting, but it's stored by the JVM, not you (not exactly sure where).  Not the keystore; that only holds keys, not settings.